# Retrieve Network Logs using Python

Tags: python

Generally, whenever a page is loaded, it sends several requests, which can be recorded in the **Network** tab in chrome developer tools.

My prime motive is to log all the network requests whenever page is loaded using python script. A sample screen-shot is attached, to illustrate what all request I am trying to collect.

[Image for Network Hit Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh0sR.png)

I am trying to achieve the same using *urllib* library in python, however, I am not exactly sure of the usage.

Looking forward for your responses. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the `urllib` family of libraries. To capture AJAX Requests you need to use something that has Javascript support... like a browser.

So your best option in this case is to use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to write a script that uses the [Selenium Web Driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to drive whatever browser you're using and then capture/log the AJAX requests being pushed out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Can you please provide specific syntax fro the same, assuming that Chrome WebDriver is used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that, it's fairly involved and you'll have to read the docs to tailor it for your particular situation